# Can a PC/Creature save vs falling when forced movement is applied if unconcious?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

Briefly, if an attack that can slide a creature knocks said creature unconscious, and then attempts to slide him over the edge of a cliff... does that creature get a save vs falling/hindering terrain?

DM discretion?

I decided no, he does not get the save throw in the session I am DMing... thoughts from the community?

Comment: Come hangout in chat sometime!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**PC makes a save...**

Unconscious states:

> The creature is helpless.
>    The creature can’t take actions.
>    The creature takes a -5 penalty to all defenses.
>    The creature is unaware of its surroundings.
>    The creature falls prone, if possible.
>    The creature can’t flank. -Rules Compendium p. 234.

However, saving throws are not actions. You still make saves against ongoing damage and death saves while unconscious.

Forced Movement and  hindering terrain:

> Hindering Terrain: Forced movement can force targets into hindering terrain. Targets forced into hindering terrain receive a saving throw immediately before entering the unsafe square they are forced into. Success leaves the target prone at the edge of the square before entering the unsafe square. - DMG p. 44.

There's nothing I've been able to find anywhere that precludes a PC from making a save throw vs. falling off the edge of a cliff for any reason.

While this breaks verisimilitude, it does so in favor of balance.

Comment: Thanks Joshua! My brain is wired to keep things more realistic. Reality would be that you are just dead weight when you are unconscious, hence my decision not to allow the save. I guess 4.0 is full of RAW, and I just need to get used to it, or make sure my players understand how I intend to implement the rules.

Comment: @menagroth 4e is all about the RAW and I would totally go with the RAW, 4e's greatest strength is its balance in combat, but that can only actually work if anything and everything is run RAW.

Comment: @menagroth: Quite often you can justify it as luck, and the situation. A save doesn't have to imply activity (although often it makes sense that it is). For instance a creature lying flat on the ground could easily resist a sideways blast of air.thunder better than one that is standing. It all depends on context - sometimes it's fun to come up with the in-game justification.